# Only start Project if File Exists

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have two different executables, one is a login and the other is the main application.

Now, i want to make it only possible to open the login, but not the main program. Right now you can open the main app just by clicking on it.

The login app creates a small txt file with some information, and the main program then starts and deletes the file.

**Is there a way to make the main program only start if this one file exists? So that nobody can start the main app without the login first.**

So, when you login, the app checks with a mysql database if your account exists.
Then this runs:

```
    string übergabeparameter = Convert.ToString(typ);
       string filename = (@"C:\Users\viuser\Desktop\test\dat.exe");
        var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename, übergabeparameter);

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText("fluff.txt"))
        {
            sw.Write(benutzername + System.Environment.NewLine + typ);
        }


        Close();
```

Then dat.exe starts, and runs this:

```
     bürgerlichername = File.ReadLines("fluff.txt").First();
        string line = File.ReadLines("fluff.txt").Skip(1).Take(1).First();

        if (line == "1") 
        {
            typ = "Trainer";
        }
        else
        {
            typ = "Lehrling";
        };
     System.IO.File.Delete("fluff.txt");
```

I created both apps in visual studio with wpf and c#.

Comment: got some code you tried?

Comment: In your main app start check if file exists (`File.Exists(filename)`) and then start it

Comment: Give some detail about your app. Is the login and Main app are in same assembly or they are separate projects

Comment: I don't think so. I think you'll need to check for the file when main starts and end if the file does not exist.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just add `if(File.Exists(filename)) { Application.Run(new MainForm()); }`

Comment: Bad idea. If someone finds out that this file is needed he could just create an own one and copy it into the directory. Even if checking the content, the user could save this created content one time and use it without logging in again. Instead of this, you should create a single project that starts with a login and then opens the main form.

Comment: @waqarhabib they are in seperate projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the startup code for the main app check for the file. If the file don't exist you can message the user to launch the correct exe (login). I would also have the login add some kind of hash code so the main program knows the login is legit to protect against faking the login or maybe a an old txt file that didn't get deleted after a previous login (main org might have crashed or other abend before deleting file.)

Comment: Thank you this helped me alot! I already have a hash code for the passwords in my mysql database, so i will use these to protect the app.